# Why is the camera stream loading but is not visible in the browser window?

Tags: javascript, frontend, webapi, navigator

I'm trying to access my camera as a video element but when i run the programme it is not visible.

Here's my code:

```
const myvideo=document.createElement('video');
myvideo.muted=true;

const videoGrid=document.getElementById("video_grid");

//I'm using a div element with id "video_grid" in my HTML file.This div does not contain any data (or child element) every property is set to default.

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video:true,
    audio:true
}).then((stream)=>{
    addVideoElement(myvideo,stream);
}).catch((e)=>console.log(e.name +":"+e.message ));

const addVideoElement=(video,stream)=>
{
    video.srcObject=stream;
    video.addEventListener('loadmetadata',()=>{
        video.play();
    });
    videoGrid.append(video);
}

//HTML
<body>
  <div id="video_grid">
  </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

The video stream is only visible after I click show controls button. Can you help me to fix this?

Here's an example:
[image: Example]

[this is the camera view i get after clicking show controls and now i can play it manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sF1Cv.png)

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm sorry. Is it understandable now?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like it would provide better context if we could also see the HTML and CSS of it, but a quick look at your code shows this attempt to getElementById:

```
const videoGrid=document.getElementById("video_grid");
```

But there is no id to be found. Perhaps adding this will help your code get the element properly:

```
myvideo.id=""video_grid"
```

Comment: Sorry but  i thought the HTML is self explanatory. I have edited my post Pls take a look.